# Creating a composite Field in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to create a custom composite field in Dynamics CRM that takes two single line text fields and displays them in a flyout menu just like contact full name which takes first and last name through flyout and displays them in the full name field.

Answer (score 3):

The only way of doing that is create html/js/css webresource and embed it to entity form.